# How to add a page to navbar-menu ?Asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net, navbar, asp.net-mvc-5

This is Layout view :

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("News", "Index", "ContentHtml")</li>
                @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("Guest"))
                    {


                           <li>@Html.Action("Menu"))</li>
```

This is the Menu partial view :

```
@model IEnumerable< abc.Models.Test>

   @foreach(var item in Model.Where(m => m.Show== true))
    {
       <li> 
          @Html.ActionLink("P", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) 
       </li>
    }
```

And this is the controller function:

```
public ActionResult Menu()
{
  return PartialView("Menu", db.Test.ToList().Where(m => m.Show == true).ToList());
}
```

What I want to do is , when the field Show is true, show that page in a tab in the navbar menu like this:

```
 if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("Guest"))
 {
    //Page comes here
    <li>@Html.Action("Menu"))</li> 

 }
```

Comment: You mean when you click on a menu, it should open or redirect to a page?

Comment: Yes , the menu tabs are like index , about , contact, news , P , P , P .. because i have only three pages on database with Show==true . And when i click in one of the P-s , it should redirect to details page of that page

Comment: `@foreach(var item in Model.Where(m => m.Show== true))` you dont have to check for `Show==true` here as the Model is already a List<> which contains objects that have Show==true by this filter `db.Test.ToList().Where(m => m.Show == true).ToList()`

Comment: @ttgg what error are u facing? your code seems ok

Comment: i really dont know what it happened , but it works now fine , with exceptions !!! Anyway thank you man !